# Goto label not defined c++

Tags: c++, scope, label, goto

Why doesn't this goto work? After the player writes a number, it should boot them back to the main menu, instead, the compiler gives label MainMenu not defined c++

```
int main()
{
    while (alive){
        MainMenu:
    }
}

void InfoPanel(){
    int choice;

    cout<<"1. Go back"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1){
        goto MainMenu;
    }
    else{
        goto MainMenu;
    }
}
```

This is how the function is called

```
int MainMenuChoice;

cout<<"5.Open info panel"<<endl;
         cin>>MainMenuChoice;

 switch(MainMenuChoice){
    case 1:
        BuildingPanel();
    break;
    case 2:
        ArmyPanel();
    break;
    case 3:
        DiplomacyPanel();
    break;
    case 4:
        ActionsPanel();
    break;
    case 5:
        InfoPanel();
        goto MainMenu;
    break;
    default:
        cout<<"that doesnt seem to be correct";
        goto MainMenu;
    }
```

Comment: Labels have a function scope, so you can't jump from function to function with labels.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Ok, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @DaugirdasPelanis "fix"? it isn't broken

Comment: @gkhaos it gives the error of label MainMenu not defined

Comment: @DaugirdasPelanis it would help if you provided a [mcve] where you show where you call `InfoPanel` so it's easier to understand what exactly you're trying to do and to find an alternative.

Comment: @DaugirdasPelanis make sure you understand the very first comment from mediocrevegetable1 (which actually should be an answer).

Comment: It's still not fully clear where exactly this new snippet is in your main function, but I suppose one solution could be to have `InfoPanel` return a value to judge whether to jump or not. It's also probably a better idea to use a loop in this case.

Comment: @DaugirdasPelanis -- *Why doesn't this goto work?* -- Drop using `goto` and use structured programming.   If you continue using `goto` like this, you will wind up with [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#:~:text=Spaghetti%20code%20is%20a%20pejorative,with%20insufficient%20ability%20or%20experience.), and few, if anyone is going to help you with code that is in that form.  They're not going to waste their time trying to untangle the spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **goto** doesn't work because your label *MainMenu:* is not visible for *Infopanel* function as it`s defined in main and has scope visibility so it can be used just in main block.

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ 14 Standard (3.3.5 Function scope)

> 1 Labels (6.1) have function scope and may be used anywhere in the
> function in which they are declared. Only labels have function scope.

And within the function `InfoPanel`

```
void InfoPanel(){
    int choice;

    cout<<"1. Go back"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1){
        goto MainMenu;
    }
    else{
        goto MainMenu;
    }
}
```

the label `MainMenu` is not defined. So the compiler issues an error message.

It is a bad idea to use the goto statement. Instead use a loop in main within which the function `InfoPanel` will be called.